# I am using gulp-autoprefixer and it doesn't work no matter what options I will choose

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Everything is working correctly except autoprefixer. BrowserSync is reloading, in devTools lines are showen from sass files, but when I try to apply some flexbox, in my destination file main.css unfortunately there is no effect with autoprefixer. Could you please help me with that?

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// compile scss into css
function style() {
    // 1. where is my scss file
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')

    // 2. pass that file through sass compiler & error log
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version'], cascade: false})
    // 3. where do I save the compiled CSS?
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))

    // 4. stream changes to all browser
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()))
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `overrideBrowserslist: ['last 2 version']` instead of `browsers: ['last 2 version']`?